# how to run the command pip3 install tensorflow on linux mint

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, linux-mint

i run the command above on linux mint and python3.
i get the error:

```
Failed building wheel for grpcio
```

and also

Command

```
/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lm1pg4la/grpcio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-r4j8ens0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lm1pg4la/grpcio/
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem with this commands

```py
pip3 install --upgrade pip3

sudo apt update && apt install -qy python3-pip time

sudo time pip3 install grpcio == 1.31.0
```

or used a downgrade it to 49.6.0 and try installing it will work.

```py
pip install setuptools==49.6.0
```

Comment: similar thread https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24037